# Saving .tif stack with PIL/Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I have a bunch of .tif images in a directory, and I am trying to open them using `PIL` and saving them as a single .tif file where each image is a frame. Which in principle should be possible according to this: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3636#issuecomment-508058396

So far I got:

```py
from PIL import Image

img_frames = ['test_imgs/img1.tif',
            'test_imgs/img2.tif',
            'test_imgs/img3.tif']

# read the images and store them in a list
ordered_image_files = []
for img in img_frames:
    with Image.open(img) as temp_img:
        ordered_image_files.append(temp_img)

# save the first image and add the rest as frames
ordered_image_files[0].save('test.tif', 
                            save_all = True, 
                            append_images = ordered_image_files[1:])
```

Running this gives me:

```py
AttributeError: 'TiffImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_read'
```

If I print the image objects and their classes I get:

```py
> print(ordered_image_files[0])
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=I;16B size=512x512 at 0x1028C6550>
```

```py
> print(type(ordered_image_files[0]))
<class 'PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile'>
```

So I think the reading part is fine.

I am new to image processing so perhaps I am missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Complete error trace:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mpages/miniconda3/envs/denoise_n2v/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 161, in load
    read = self.load_read
AttributeError: 'TiffImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_read'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "img_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    append_images = ordered_image_files[1:])
  File "/Users/mpages/miniconda3/envs/denoise_n2v/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2050, in save
    self._ensure_mutable()
  File "/Users/mpages/miniconda3/envs/denoise_n2v/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 640, in _ensure_mutable
    self._copy()
  File "/Users/mpages/miniconda3/envs/denoise_n2v/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 633, in _copy
    self.load()
  File "/Users/mpages/miniconda3/envs/denoise_n2v/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1098, in load
    return super(TiffImageFile, self).load()
  File "/Users/mpages/miniconda3/envs/denoise_n2v/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 165, in load
    read = self.fp.read
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Please show the complete error trace.

Comment: I updated my answer if you'd care to have another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your `with` statement is closing your image file or putting it out of some memory context in which it can be accessed, so you could try this which works fine on my Mac:

```
for img in img_frames: 
    ordered_image_files.append(Image.open(img))
```

---

Failing that, I had some success with the `tifffile` module, as follows:

```
import tifffile
img_frames = [ '1.tif', '2.tif', '3.tif' ]

with tifffile.TiffWriter('multipage.tif') as stack: 
    for filename in img_frames: 
        stack.save(tifffile.imread(filename))
```

**Keywords**: Python, TIF, TIFF, tifffile, multi-page, multipage, sequence, image, image processing

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried what you suggested, but with my real image dataset I have more than 3 images (~400). Which gives this error: `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files:`. So I think I need to close the files at some point, that is the reason for the `with` statement.

Comment: If you are on macOS or Linux, you should be able to increase the limit of open file-descriptors with something like `ulimit -n 2048` Try `help ulimit`

Comment: I did not try increasing the `ulimit`, but using the `tifffile` library did work, many thanks!